# Как отменить оповещение о зависании страницы?

Tags: javascript, браузер

Есть обычная страница сайта, на ней проводятся долгие расчеты (20с. - 5мин.) Через 30 секунд в браузере появляется сообщение что страница зависла. Конечно можно нажать кнопку "продолжить", но желательно вообще убрать "зависание", т.к. скрипт еще считает время выполнения. Возможно ли как-то включить фоновый режим, отправлять информацию о том что скрипт нормально работает в апи браузера?

Comment: Это что за сообщение? По-моему в браузере ничего такого нет

Comment: @Inventor когда цикл работает 30+ секунд. https://shumik.site/lab/AnDS/01.php# попробуйте запустить сортировку пузырьком (бульбашка) на 10 000 элементов

Comment: @Inventor когда цикл очень долго работает - браузер видит это как зависание страницы

Comment: Не понимаю что это за сайт и что я там должен делать, чтобы получить этот эффект)

Comment: @Inventor там где 15 напишите 10 000, нажмите int, а когда появляться числа - нажмите на любую стрелочку возле "Л.1 Бульбашка з прапорцем"

Comment: Я понял о чём вы, не знаю сработает ли, но попробуйте через `setTimeout(func, 0)` запустить функцию. Если не поможет, то посмотрите на это: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: @Inventor не работает

Comment: Добавил ответ  ниже

Comment: Просто не нужно выполнять такие длительные **синхронные** вычисления в браузере.

Comment: @vp_arth синхронные?

Comment: Да, js - однопоточный. Если вы выполняете много вычислений в рамках одного синхронного фрейма(например, в обычных циклах), весь поток «зависает», ждёт окончания работы вашего скрипта. Нужно разбивать задачу на небольшие куски, и откладывать их выполнение в event loop(например, с помощью setTimeout) Таким образом, другой код(обновление DOM, реакция на действия пользователя) сможет выполняться между чанками ваших вычислений.

Comment: Ну или просто убирайте вычисления в другой поток, в WebWorker, как вам уже ответили))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что ваш основной поток слишком долго не отвечает. Вам нужно перенести ваши вычисления в фоновый режим. Для этого используйте [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)

Comment: А что значит "не отвечает"? Только что попробовал использовать веб воркеры, создал отдельную страницу. Для теста запустил цикл, чтобы узнать на каком этапе зависнет - крутится по 100+ секунд и все хорошо. Почему тогда при сортировке зависает на 30+?

Comment: Теперь пробую на изначальной странице - совсем пропала ошибка) Теперь считает до конца и не говорит что зависло. Не знаю, с чем это может быть связано

Comment: @shumik_UA браузер следит за вашим основным потоком, если в этом потоке на протяжении 30 секунд, не прерываясь выполняется код, то браузер считает, что окно зависло. Web worker - отдельный поток, который выполняется в фоновом режиме, там код может выполняться сколько угодно, браузер не следит за этим, главное, чтобы ваш основной поток не был занят постоянно и мог реагировать на действия пользователя